# Is it possible to design SPDT switch without using relay or any mechanical part?

Tags: switches, circuit-design, potentiometer

We have system like on the photo below. These logarithmic potentiometers(10k Ohm) are adjusting motor speed. One potentiometer is used to adjust speed of motor when door contact is closed(door is open) and other one is when door is closed(it is adjusted to %20 of speed in standby mode)

Normally, door contact is connected to relay which is supplied by 20V but in some variants, 20V is not possible.

I would like ask if there is any possibility to switch between potentiometers without relay. Another idea can be switching 10V instead of A1 but I couldn't find a proper way with full potential(10V)

Idea is to make it as cheap as possible.

PS: Normally door contact is just on/off. not a spdt.

[image]

Comment: What is the pot resistance?

Comment: @BruceAbbott 10k

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the High Voltage, Single Supply SPDT Analog Switches such as the DG469 with +/- 15V switching capability or any similar SPDT analogue switch ? They are generally used to replace such relays for space constraint applications or where signal speed is too high for normal relays. You will need to find one that handles switching of signals that is within your maximum requirement (20V or 10V etc). Good luck !

Comment: I haven't known it. I will check. Thanks